# SpringBoot 1.5+ junit test does not load configuration with custom name

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit

I am working on setting up spring boot application and I wish to use custom file name for configuration instead of application.yml. Reason for that is server side tomcat that is running those applications.

I have application class defined:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"com.example"})
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("spring.config.name", "myapp");
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.properties("spring.config.name: myapp").sources(Application.class);
    }
    ...
```

And configuration named myapp.yml

In JUnit test I have following annotations:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {Application.class})
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = {ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class})
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class UserTest {
...
```

And pom dependencies for junit:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jmockit</groupId>
        <artifactId>jmockit</artifactId>
        <version>1.31</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-restdocs-mockmvc</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
<!-- if I remove this dependency then normal application works with custom name but if I have it in dependencies then mvn spring-boot:run does not find configuration either -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
        <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I tried many different things but I cannot get it to work as I want. I want my own file name for configuration and then solve different configurations with @ActiveProfiles annotation. Thank you!

Comment: Your `main` method isn't executed when starting a test, so obviously setting things in there won't work. Use a `@BeforeClass` annotated method to set the desired property.

Comment: I did not checked if main is actually issued! I would find out the rest for myself if I'd check that. Thank you for that useful information!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @M.Deinum mentioned you should initialize property in @BeforeClass method in test class:

```
@BeforeClass
public static void initProperties() {
    System.setProperty("spring.config.name", "myapp"); 
}
```

Good practice is to tidy up properties after the test, so that other tests are not affected by these properties

```
@AfterClass
public static void clearProperties() {
    System.clearProperty("spring.config.name"); 
}
```

BUT THERE IS BETTER OPTION TO USE TEST PROPERTIES:

You should use application.yaml in your tests as well. Your dynamical configuration (e.g. DB credentials) shouldn't be placed in this config file. They should be passed to application via env property (hence [12 factor app principles](https://12factor.net/config)).

During testing, there are various ways how to define this dynamical configuration. E.g.:

1. With above mentioned mechanism `@BeforeClass` + `System.setPRoperty`
2. Or you would use additional test config file via `@TestProperties` annotation or `SpringBootTest.properties` attribute

Comment: This worked for me. I put that in abstract class so it's called every time I want to use "test" profile. Thank you for quick response! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have custom configuration named `application-test.yml` instead of `application.yml`.

You just need to add following to your test class,

`@SpringBootTest(value={"spring.profiles.active=test"})`

This way you avoid setting config properties and again resetting them specifically in `@BeforeTest` and `@AfterTest`.

Hope it helps !

Comment: This is true, but only this does not work if I want to have custom name instead of default "application". Accepted answer also explains why this is not working. Thanks